# How to load javascript file before css file using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have two external files: JavaScript file and Css file, I need to load js before css using Jquery.

Comment: << I need to load js before css using Jquery>> Why would you need this?

Comment: Add the `link` tag pointing to the CSS file to the document during your JS script.

Comment: Then let jQuery load the CSS :)

Comment: Why would you do this EVER?

Answer (score 2):

You can let jQuery load the CSS like this, after all the other scripts have loaded:

```
$('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />', {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    type: 'text/css',
    href: '/path/to/css'
}).appendTo('head');
```

You can also load JavaScript with jQuery:

```
$.getScript('/path/to/js', function() {
    // script loaded
});
```

Comment: I need to load js first not css.

Comment: @user2456908 Then use `$.getScript()` first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery.load() or jQuery.getScript()..